# Django: Create a model field referencing a ForeignKey field

Tags: django, django-models

In a Django, given a Person model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    person_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False, default="")
```

and a Member model which has a person as a Foreign Key:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    member_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, blank=False, null=False)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

I'm looking to be able to add a field to the Member model which contains the name of the person.

I've tried:
`name = person.name` and
`name = self.person.name`
with no luck.

I *could* define a function:

```
def name(self):
    return self.person.name
```

...but then I would need to reference it with parens: `member.name()`

And, of course, I could always just reference it via `member.person.name`, but that's so verbose.

Is there a way to define this attribute?

Comment: can you not define a method in `Member` as `def person_name(self): return self.person.name` ?

Comment: I could, as in the example 2/3 through the post (edited to include self parameter). But then I would need to call member.name() with parens. Not the end of the world, but my question is whether I can avoid it.

Comment: could you explain further what you are trying to achive or why using parens is a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`@property` as a decorator.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

```
@property
def name(self):
    return self.person.name
```

Now, you can just reference it as

```
member.name
```

instead of `member.name()`

Now, `name` is treated as a property on `Member` class, instead of a class method.